# Getting specific columns with eager loading laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

I am new to laravel and making a basic application to get a grip on relationships.I have implemented one to one relationship and want to get specific columns from both the base table and the related table.I have two tables namely users and identity_cards.Relationship is defined as follows

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
     protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    //protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    protected $fillable = array('first_name','last_name','email','created_at','updated_at');

    public function identity_cards() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne('IdentityCard');
    }
}


class IdentityCard extends Eloquent {

    protected $table    = 'identity_cards';
    protected $fillable = array('issuance_date','expiry_date','issuance_location','user_id');
    public $timestamps  = false;

    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when i try to retrieve all the columns

```
$users = User::with('identity_cards')->get()->toArray();
```

But when i try to get specific columns from either or both the tables,i got an empty array against the record for identity card table

```
 $users = User::with(array('identity_cards'),function($query) {
                $query->select('issuance_location'); //getting specific column from identity card table
              }
          )->get(array("first_name"))->toArray();
```

Result against the above statement is as follows:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => User1
        [identity_cards] => 
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => User2
        [identity_cards] => 
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => User3
        [identity_cards] => 
    )

 )
```

This can be achieved using query builder but i want the solution with eloquent.Why am i getting an empty array for my related table even if i have the data in it.How specific columns can be fetched using eager loading??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 You need to always select `primary key` of the parent and `foreign key` of the child of a relation, otherwise Eloquent won't be able to match related models.

2 Closure passed to the eager loading is a value of the array, not 2nd parameter of `with` function:

```
User::with(array('identity_cards' => function($query) {
            $query->select('issuance_location', 'user_id');
      }))->get(array('first_name', 'id'))->toArray();
```

3 I would rename that relation to `identity_card`, for it's `hasOne` - it will be easier to work with.

Comment: Mark it as correct answer then, in case anyone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution would be just making a new relation similar to that you have made, but tweaking it a bit, for conviniece :

```
public function identity_cards_limited() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne('IdentityCard')->select('desired_column');
    }
```

Comment: I saw this option but this will limit my scope when i want to retrieve one set of columns for one query and other set for another query.For example,in one scenerio i need id and expiry date of card and in other scenerio, i need issuance date only.For table with greater number of columns this would be an overhead to specify many column names.But yes this is a good option too :).Thanks for your help :)