# Eager loading in Laravel returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I started using the eager loader in Laravel 4.

I have two tables (campaigns and reports) whit following relation in the Campaigns Model:

```
public function reports() {
   return $this->hasMany('Reports', 'account_id', 'adwords_id')->select('CLICKS', 'COST');
}
```

I had to use non-conventional column names here unfortunaly.

When I now do:

```
$data['campaigns'] = Campaign::get();
foreach ($data['campaigns'] as $campaign) {
  print_r($campaign->reports);
}
```

it outputs all the reports for the campaigns the way it should.

But now I want to eager load this:

```
$data['campaigns'] = Campaign::with('reports')->get();
foreach ($data['campaigns'] as $campaign) {
   print_r($campaign->reports);
}
```

This outputs me just empty arrays.

What am I doing wrong?
I really want to use eager to have fasters scripts...

Comment: Duplicate, read this: [Getting specific columns with eager loading laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906790/getting-specific-columns-with-eager-loading-laravel-4#25907624)

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I had to select the keys. Strange that it worked when not using Eager Loader even without having the key selected.

Comment: Not that strange. If you tried to load that relation on a `collection` then it wouldn't work as well, however when you do it on a single parent, then there is no need for matching `parents - children`, so basically whatever comes from the query is set as a relation on the parent model.