# Laravel limit with (not globally)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query I want to execute with `Eloquent`.

```
$restaurant = Restaurant::with([
    'user' => function($query)
    {
        $query->select(['username']); // This doesn't work
        $query->whereStatus('confirmed');
    }
])->find($id);
```

I want to fetch a `Restaurant` and it's corresponding `User` (they are related) but from the `User` I don't wan't all the information. Only the `username` in this case.

I could add a property `$hidden` to the `User` model, but then they would be hidden for every query (in array / json form). But I only want to limit it a bit more for this query.

If I add the select (with or without wrapping it in an array) I get the following result:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'user': null
}
```

Yet if I remove that select I get the full `User`:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'user': { .. json user data }
}
```

The `User` does exist and the `username` is not empty. How can I go about this?

Here the [actual](https://gist.github.com/Matthijn/d3b3175c6a5112308355) output can be found.

Edit: When I change the value in the select to something that does not exist in the database I see an error, and from that I deduct that the Query is correct, but I just don't get any output. (Query I get when using an invalid column 'test').

```
select `test` from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`userable_id` in (1) and `users`.`userable_type` = Restaurant and `status` = confirmed)
```

Comment: **Primary & foreign key of the relation**: Once again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906790/getting-specific-columns-with-eager-loading-laravel-4/25907624#25907624 - upvote and have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$restaurant = Restaurant::with([
    'user' => function($query)
    {
        $query->whereStatus('confirmed')->lists('username');
    }
])->find($id);
```

**EDIT**

It seems that both methods will work but you need to fulfil one condition - you need to include foreign_key column in the lists/select. I don't know what is your relation but for example assuming you have in `users` table  `restaurant_id` column you would need to use the following code:

```
$restaurant = Restaurant::with([
    'user' => function($query)
    {
        $query->select(['username', 'restaurant_id'])->whereStatus('confirmed');
    }
])->find($id);
```

or

```
$restaurant = Restaurant::with([
    'user' => function($query)
    {
        $query->whereStatus('confirmed')->lists('username','restaurant_id');
    }
])->find($id);
```

I don't know if it is possible for n:n relationship. You should also consider that this might be a bit dangerous (some problems may occur) so you should play with it only if you have strong reason just to grab selected columns.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference. (Added a Json gist of my responses in TS).