# Laravel select specific column when eager loading collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

Take the following code snippet. I am loading the `OrderDetail` model with the relationship to `Inventory`:

```
// Load order details for live orders and inventory ids
$order_details = \OrderDetail::whereIn('order_id', $live_order_ids)
    ->whereIn('inventory_id', $inventory_ids)
    ->with('inventory')
    ->get();
```

Once the collection is loaded, I am doing the following processing:

```
// Deduct reserved stock from live un-picked orders
foreach ($order_details as $detail)
    if (array_key_exists($detail->inventory->sku, $free_stocks))
        $free_stocks[$detail->inventory->sku] -= 
            ($detail->qty_ordered - $detail->qty_picked);
```

As you can see, from the loaded collection, I only need the following:

- order_details.qty_ordered
- order_details.qty_picked
- inventory.sku

I'd like to optimise this and only load what I require, i.e. specify explcitly what columns I want to load from the main and related table.

How can I do this? When I tried the following, it doesn't seem to work:

```
// Load order details for live orders and inventory ids
$order_details = \OrderDetail::whereIn('order_id', $live_order_ids)
    ->whereIn('inventory_id', $inventory_ids)
    ->with('inventory')
    ->get(['qty_ordered','qty_picked','sku']);
```

---

```
// Load order details for live orders and inventory ids
$order_details = \OrderDetail::whereIn('order_id', $live_order_ids)
    ->whereIn('inventory_id', $inventory_ids)
    ->with(['inventory' => function($query) {
        $query->addSelect(['id','sku']);
    }])
    ->get(['qty_ordered','qty_picked']);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/25907624/784588

Answer (score 0):

You need to use select in query to get selected columns. Or if it will not work you need use laravel joins.

Also Please see select columns from queries in laravel official document.
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries.

```
// Load order details for live orders and inventory ids
$order_details = \OrderDetail::whereIn('order_id', $live_order_ids)
    ->whereIn('inventory_id', $inventory_ids)
    ->with(['inventory' => function($query) {
        $query->addSelect(['id','sku']);
    }])
    ->select('qty_ordered','qty_picked')
->get();
```

Comment: Or in this way. $order_details = \OrderDetail::whereIn('order_id', $live_order_ids)
    ->whereIn('inventory_id', $inventory_ids)
    ->inventory()
->get(['inventory.sku','qty_ordered','qty_picked'])->toArray();